# JQuery 1.7.2 min.js versions is not working with CRM2011 roll up 12

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

There are few issues has been given when running the **CustomCodeValidationTool** .

Can someone tell me what would be the best jQuery version to work with CRM 2011 roll up 12?

Below **errors** were given by the  **CustomCodeValidationTool**.

> was located 1 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .text was located 14 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> ActiveXObject( was located 2 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .attachEvent( was located 4 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .childNodes.length was located 4 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .firstChild was located 29 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .lastChild was located 4 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .nextSibling was located 9 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .previousSibling was located 2 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .contains( was located 8 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> dblclick was located 1 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .dir was located 6 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .innerText was located 3 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .outerHTML was located 4 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .currentStyle was located 9 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> opacity= was located 3 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .srcElement was located 1 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .returnValue was located 2 time(s) in this web resource.
>
> .add( was located 11 time(s) in this web resource.

Answer (score 4):

The only supported use of jQuery in Dynamics CRM form javascripts is the ajax method. Read more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328261.aspx#BKMK_UsingjQuery

Other jQuery usage will work, but is not officialy supported by Microsoft. Anyway - you should use a newer version of jQuery! If you need to support IE 6/7/8 you should use jQuery 1.10.x, if you don`t need to support these browser you should use 2.x.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the jQuery.ajax exception, do you mind if I include it in my answer?

Comment: No problem. just add it to your answer:)

Comment: Thanks a lot.i had this issue with WYSIWYG Editor.So i have change the editor to the below one.http://chamarairesh.blogspot.com/2013/07/rich-text-box-with-crm-2011-rollup-12.html

Answer (score 2):

`Custom Code Validation Tool` checks for potential issues in JavaScript libraries and HTML Web Resources.

If you try to validate `jQuery` library the tool will always return errors, because it only tries to match a list of keywords.

Example from `jQuery` source code:

```js
if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard
    tmp = new DOMParser();
    xml = tmp.parseFromString( data , "text/xml" );
} else { // IE
    xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
    xml.async = "false";
    xml.loadXML( data );
}
```

as you can see there is the keyword `ActiveXObject` but the code is cross-browser compatible, this is a false positive, because

> [The tool also cannot determine the intent of the script being analyzed.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2012/06/21/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-custom-code-validation-tool-released.aspx#FalsePositives)

If you want to use `jQuery` inside CRM 2011 is better to use it only inside HTML Web Resources, this because HTML Web Resources are rendered as `IFRAME` making your code a separate entity from the CRM Forms.

As [Svendberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231959/svendberg) pointed out in his answer, the only supported use of jQuery in CRM 2011 Forms is to use the `jQuery.ajax` method to retrieve data from the `REST` endpoint.

If you are using `jQuery` inside a CRM Form to perform `DOM` manipulations you will always have potential issues, because inside CRM Forms you need to use only the `Xrm` Object to interact with controls and values.

Comment: Use of jQuery -- This is Useful : ---- > 
Do not use jQuery to interact with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 forms. Use the Xrm.Page object model methods to access form elements.
The only supported use of jQuery in the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online web application is to use the jQuery.ajax method to retrieve data from the REST endpoint. For more information, see Using jQuery. Using jQuery to modify Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 application pages or forms is not supported. You may use jQuery within your own HTML web resource pages.